# Delete the first row and move all the rows upward

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I have this MySQL table:

```
======================================================
=ID=    User    =       Message       =   Timestamp  =
======================================================
= 1=    user1234=      Example Message=    1401959529=
= 2=     krimson=      Just a test hey=    1401959535=
= 3=     boomhey=      Don't mind that=    1401959537=
= 4=   viceganda=           I'm pretty=    1401959543=
= 5=   annevhong= We don't really mind=    1401959544=
======================================================
```

Where `ID` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. What code should I use so that the first when the rows become **5**, and I enter the **6<sup>th</sup>** line, the first line would be deleted, and all rows will go up and will become:

```
======================================================
=ID=    User    =       Message       =   Timestamp  =
======================================================
= 1=     krimson=      Just a test hey=    1401959535=
= 2=     boomhey=      Don't mind that=    1401959537=
= 3=   viceganda=           I'm pretty=    1401959543=
= 4=   annevhong= We don't really mind=    1401959544=
= 5=     newuser=           newmessage=    1401959548=
======================================================
```

I also prefer to use PHP to get this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me, but why do you want to do that? Is going to consume a lot of resources doing it and worse: is going to make you lose your ids and relations in case you want to make a RDBS.

Comment: This is not how RDBMSs or auto incrementing ids are used typically. Please do not confuse an RDBMS data store with a spreadsheet. *Why* do you actually want to do this? There's likely a much better solution to accomplish what you're trying to do more in line with RDBMS data stores.

Comment: Re-assigning and AUTOINCREMENT id is usually a bad idea, why do you need that?

Comment: We can see what you want, that's great. Have you done anything to get there on your own?

Comment: I'm still brainstorming on how to build a PHP and AJAX-based chat. But, if I use .txt files for logging down chat conversations, when the  chat gets long enough, it would consume large space, and also bandwidth. And I don't really know a way on how to delete the older messages on a .txt file using PHP. So, I prefer using databases as you can interact with each row on it. Do you have any better ideas other than this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this because you only want the most recent 5 records, in that case I'd strongly recommend using a view instead to replicate this, rather than making this intensive change repeatedly and losing data.

Comment: Because if I do not delete older messages, that would consume a lot of resources.

Comment: Honestly if you're concerned about the storage requirements for this you're probably better off using something like memcached to handle the storage in memory, and simply shift the array every time you insert.

Comment: You should run a CRON to delete the old rows every hour/day/week if your problem is the size of the table. You could split the chat in several tables by month (you insert on the chat_2014_06 table the conversation, and then drop the table in july)... There are a lot of options for what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

In short: don't do it

A row has an ID, and that ID is a unique identifier. Nothing more, nothing less. It is NOT the order of your records (although practically, newer records have higher ID's). If you want the last 5 records, sort your result on `Timestamp` column in descending order. If you want to delete the oldest record, delete one record, sorted on `Timestamp` in ascending order.

But do **NOT** change the ID's of individual records (you do not change your name on every year on your birthday, do you? ;)). It will get you in all kinds of troubles, like someone in the comments noted, relations with other tables etc. And don't worry about resources, and don't worry that the integer limit will be reached (the first site that has that many users that a normal integer column isn't big enough is yet to be born...)

Comment: Twitter did have their Twitpocalypse a while back... :P

Comment: lol :p that's true, but that was due to the amount of tweets, not to the amount of users ;) And still; they did NOT move tweet-id's upward!

Answer (score 0):

never ever try to mutate the primary key. find other ways to solve the problems.
according to me you have to do this if you want to delete previous messages.
keep checking the id if the difference becomes greater than 5 then delete the upper row
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete user from the top of the user list and query will be -

```
DELETE FROM Users ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1
```

Second update all records id's like this -

```
UPDATE Users SET ID = ID-1
```

Third insert new row

```
INSERT INTO Users (ID, User, Message) VALUES ('6', 'newuser', 'newmessage')
```

Comment: Although this might work, please please please don't do this...

Comment: i am just giving solution of problem , do and don't do this its only depends on need .

Comment: Yes, and the solution is correct, but if someone asks what is the most appropriate way to jump of a building it might be a nice thing to do to also warn them it most probably isn't a very intelligent thing to do ;) So you don't have to delete your answer, but at least warn the OP that he should look out for another solution to his problem (and as the problem isn't entirely clear, we can't possibly be sure this is a correct solution...)

Answer (score 0):

you should not do this due to ID is auto increment and Primary.
then after if u want to do this then try this..

```
$id=1;
mysql_query("Delect from TableName where ID=$id");

$qry = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID > ".$id." ORDER BY ID";
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{   
    mysql_query("UPDATE TableName SET ID = ".$id." WHERE ID = ".$row["ID"];
    $id++;
}
```